# Excel Formula doesn't work with a reference, but works while typing the value being searched for

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

I have a formula that looks up data in a separate worksheet and counts how many rows have the searched for name and if they are set to "inbound". Below is my formula:

```
=countifs(seperateSheet!J:J,thisSheet!A1,seperateSheet!C:C,"Inbound)
```

This formula works for some names, but not all, despite all of the names I am searching for appearing in seperateSheet and being marked with Inbound, so I know they should be counted. For the names that don't work using references, if I type the actual name it works just fine despite the reference cell having the name spelled the exact same way. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Check for trailing spaces, or hidden characters.

Comment: That did it, thanks!